# How to implement listview from nested json data using http request in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, http, listview

I am new in flutter. i want to using http request for nested json data and want to show that data in listview. i made http request for get data. and i got 200. but problem is how to return my response for nested json data and show these data to listview? i read many documents but not properly understood. can anyone teach me how to implement this and if i made any wrong, what kind of wrong?

from json i also want to show "count", "idEmployee", "fullname" in my listview.

N.B: this api and token is just for test purpose.

**Nested Json Data**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "count": 261,
        "data": [
            {
                "idEmployee": 3588,
                "avatar": null,
                "fullName": "Moodle Connection Test",
                "officeID": "1003588",
                "email": "",
                "designation": "Senior Executive",
                "department": "Accounts",
                "mobileNumber": "",
                "workStation": "Work Station 12",
                "businessUnit": "CDA"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

**ListAlbum Model Class**

```
class ListAlbum {
  final int? idEmployee;
  final String? avatar;
  final String? fullName;
  final String? officeID;
  final String? email;
  final String? designation;
  final String? department;
  final String? mobileNumber;
  final String? workStation;
  final String? businessUnit;

  ListAlbum({
    this.idEmployee,
    this.avatar,
    this.fullName,
    this.officeID,
    this.email,
    this.designation,
    this.department,
    this.mobileNumber,
    this.workStation,
    this.businessUnit,
  });

  factory ListAlbum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ListAlbum(
      idEmployee: json['idEmployee'],
      avatar: json['avatar'],
      fullName: json['fullName'],
      officeID: json['officeID'],
      email: json['email'],
      designation: json['designation'],
      department: json['department'],
      mobileNumber: json['mobileNumber'],
      workStation: json['workStation'],
      businessUnit: json['businessUnit'],
    );
  }
}
```

**Api Calling**

```
Future<List<ListAlbum>> listData() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://portal-api.jomakhata.com/api/getOrganizationData'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Authorization':
        'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjI4OTksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcG9ydGFsLWFwaS5qb21ha2hhdGEuY29tL2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjMxNDYyNTE3LCJleHAiOjE2MzE1NDg5MTcsIm5iZiI6MTYzMTQ2MjUxNywianRpIjoiY2tXUVAya3RsdEJvTHd4QyJ9.9wkcg2n6XgWC1lAj2ZAwHJFMZIVbtg7cmo_jUN86rBo',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'limit': 5.toString(),
        'orderBy': 'idEmployee',
        'orderType': 'DESC'
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print("ok");
      print(response.body);

      return    // here how to return for nested json data?

    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to create album.');
    }
}
```

**List View**

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override

      _MyAppState createState() {
        return _MyAppState();
      }
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      late Future<List<ListAlbum>> futureAlbum;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        futureAlbum = listData();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Create Data Example',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: FutureBuilder<List<ListAlbum>>(
                future: futureAlbum,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    print(snapshot.data);
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final ListAlbum item = snapshot.data![index];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(item.fullName!),
                          subtitle: Text(item.designation!),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                  }
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, I sure hope this line :

```
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjI4OTksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcG9ydGFsLWFwaS5qb21ha2hhdGEuY29tL2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjMxNDYyNTE3LCJleHAiOjE2MzE1NDg5MTcsIm5iZiI6MTYzMTQ2MjUxNywianRpIjoiY2tXUVAya3RsdEJvTHd4QyJ9.9wkcg2n6XgWC1lAj2ZAwHJFMZIVbtg7cmo_jUN86rBo
```

Is not actually your authentication credentials because it would take very little effort to decode that, and it would compromise your entire application.

Now, regarding your question, I might be wrong, but if I recall correctly, the http package will return a **JSON** response as a String, so first things first convert it to json using:

```
Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.data);
```

Then you can use a map method to return the models:

```
return json['data']['data'].map<ListAlbum>((value) => ListAlbum.fromJson(value));
```

Haven't tested it, but I believe that should work.

Comment: Thanks, but still now it shows error. FormantException: Unexpected character (at Character 2737) ... 
can you implement for me the full code in listView?

Comment: Your ListView code is likely not the problem, the error code that you got makes me think the problem comes from the JSON response itself (specifically, it seems character 2737 is not valid JSON) I would copy and paste the entire JSON response into https://jsonlint.com/ to see if it can figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks... after solving backend i'll try and give you feedback!